# Expressão regular para negar tudo que não seja razão social

Tags: java, regex, replace

Estou tentando criar uma expressão regular para remover tudo que não for parte da razão social em uma string, porém estou tendo dificuldades para não remover os símbolos que estão no meio da mesma.

Entrada:

```
201700000000111 01/02/2017 11.111.111/0001-74 ADAMA BRASIL S/A ATIVA 0,00 160,00 160,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00
201700000000122 01/02/2017 22.222.222/0002-75 AGRITEX COMERCIAL AGRÍCOLA LTDA (QUERÊNCIA) ATIVA 2,79 170,00 170,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 4,74 0,00
201700000000133 07/02/2017 33.333.333/0001-76 CREMONESE WANDSCHEER & CIA LTDA - ME ATIVA 0,00 50,00 50,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00
201700000000144 23/02/2017 44.444.444/0001-77 G3 SEMENTES LTDA ATIVA 0,00 230,00 230,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00
```

Saída necessária:

```
ADAMA BRASIL S/A ATIVA
AGRITEX COMERCIAL AGRÍCOLA LTDA (QUERÊNCIA) ATIVA
CREMONESE WANDSCHEER & CIA LTDA - ME ATIVA
```

Atualmente criei uma da forma abaixo, porém não está ficando como eu preciso. Estou usando em java, porém podem postar de outras formas que eu adéquo o código.

```
s.replaceAll("[^A-zÀ-ú\\s]", "").trim();
```

Comment: O texto sempre começa desta posição fixa? Ou no 4º token? Isso já facilita o trabalho.

Comment: Você pode mudar a regra de sua expressão regular, em vez de buscar remover o que você não quer, vc pode fazer a a busca trazendo apenas o que você quer tipo: `\b[A-zÀ-ú\s\\\/&\-\(|)]{2,}\b` veja neste exemplo: http://rubular.com/r/4LdX3PR6s1

Comment: Editei a resposta, chegando assim a esta expressão: `\b(\d{2}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\/\d{4}\-\d{2})\b([A-zÀ-ú-1-9\s\\\/&\-\(|)]{5,}.*[a-zA-Z])\b`

Comment: Me parece totalmente dispensável a regex. Aparentemente bastaria considerar os espaços e dispensar 3 itens da esquerda e 8 da direita.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se a sentença sempre segue este padrão. Basta você verificar as fronteiras.

- Esquerda : Precedido de um CNPJ, final do CNPJ `\d{4}-\d{2}`
- Direita : Seguido de um valor monetário : `\d+,\d{2}`

#### Resolução

- Pattern : `.*\d{4}-\d{2} (.*?) \d+,\d{2}.*`
- Replace : `$1`

Veja Funcionando em [REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/fp5Af5/1)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, funcionou bem.

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde, acredito que você consiga fazer a busca do conjunto inteiro de palavras dentro da expressao:

Fiz um teste, segue abaixo:

[Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/oF90NAV188)

Definida a expressão regular voce pode fazer o escape para java com o
[freeformatter](http://www.freeformatter.com/java-dotnet-escape.html)

Conforme esta expressão consigo pegar a saída esperada desta forma:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    String input = "201700000000111 01/02/2017 11.111.111/0001-74 ADAMA BRASIL S/A ATIVA 0,00 160,00 160,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00"
            + System.lineSeparator()
            + "201700000000122 01/02/2017 22.222.222/0002-75 AGRITEX COMERCIAL AGRÍCOLA LTDA (QUERÊNCIA) ATIVA 2,79 170,00 170,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 4,74 0,00"
            + System.lineSeparator()
            + "201700000000133 07/02/2017 33.333.333/0001-76 CREMONESE WANDSCHEER & CIA LTDA - ME ATIVA 0,00 50,00 50,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00"
            + System.lineSeparator()
            + "201700000000204 23/02/2017 23.972.199/0001-15 G3 SEMENTES LTDA ATIVA 0,00 230,00 230,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00";

    String regex = "\\b(\\d{2}\\.\\d{3}\\.\\d{3}\\/\\d{4}\\-\\d{2})\\b([A-zÀ-ú-1-9\\s\\\\\\/&\\-\\(|)]{5,}.*[a-zA-Z])\\b";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        String cnpj = matcher.group(1).trim();
        String nome = matcher.group(2).trim();
        System.out.println(nome);
    }

}
```

Agora explicando minha expressão regular:

`\b(\d{2}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\/\d{4}\-\d{2})\b([A-zÀ-ú-1-9\s\\\/&\-\(|)]{5,}.*[a-zA-Z])\b`

O `\b` antes e depois significa que pode existir qualquer caracter especial antes e depois da expressão regular, que é definida pelo conjunto de caracteres entre `[]` onde ocorrem 5 vezes ou mais em sequencia. 
Você pode ir adicionando mais caracteres dentro de `[]` conforme a necessidade
Outro ponto importante aqui foi utilizar o `group` basicamente tudo o que fica entre parênteses são agrupamentos, utilizei 2. O primeiro agrupamento é o padrão de cnpj e o segundo agrupamento é o padrão de sequencia para o nome.

quando você utiliza group[1](http://rubular.com/r/oF90NAV188) você vai recuperar o cnpj 
quando você utiliza group[2](http://www.freeformatter.com/java-dotnet-escape.html) você vai recuperar o nome

Veja o funcionamento no [ideone](https://ideone.com/jrLCq2)

Espero ter ajudado abraço

Comment: Opa, boa tarde...
Funcionou, porém me deparei com problema de ter número no meio, será que tem alguma forma de passar por isso também? tentei alterar sua expressão, porém não obtive sucesso.

Exemplo:
201700000000204 23/02/2017 23.972.199/0001-15 G3 SEMENTES LTDA ATIVA 0,00 230,00 230,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00

Comment: Tenho outra solução, vc pode trabalhar com o `group`, basicamente mapear o cnpj seguido da expressao do nome, quando vc utiliza o group 1 vc tem o cnpj e quando utilizar o group 2 terá o nome completo

Comment: Consegui chegar a esta expressão `\b(\d{2}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\/\d{4}\-\d{2})\b([A-zÀ-ú-1-9\s\\\/&\-\(|)]{5,}.*[a-zA-Z])\b` editei a resposta veja se funciona

Comment: Obrigado, foi de grande ajuda.